# Caching BIND server not returning RFC1918 PTR records

Tags: bind, reverse-dns

We have a Debian stretch server running Bind 9.10 as a local caching DNS service to applications running on that server. This local caching DNS service sends its queries to our institution's main DNS servers. Our institution's main DNS servers have RFC1918 entries. However, our caching DNS server cannot seem to get PTR records for these 1918 addresses.

More precisely, a query such as this:

```
nslookup 10.111.1.227
```

works the *first* time after a Bind restart but then fails with an `NXDOMAIN` every time thereafter.

Here is the bind `named.conf` file:

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        // Only accept queries from localhost                                                 
        listen-on port 53       { 127.0.0.1; };
        allow-query             { localhost; };
        recursion yes;
        max-cache-size 50000000;
        disable-empty-zone "10.in-addr.arpa";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RFC1918 zones are blackholed when following normal delegation path. You probably need to create forward, slave or stub zones for these zones in your bind config unless you are maintaining your own internal DNS root zone.